# How to delete specific character from a huge records in database MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character

I have many records in the database, and I would like to delete a specific character from all records in specific column.

for example I have this table

```
id cost    distance  
1  $1,519  21.5 miles   
2  $7,987  32.789 miles
```

I would like to remove all dollar signs and comma in the cost column as well I would like to delete the the word miles from distance column

so I want the final result to be

```
id cost  distance  
1  1519  21.5  
2  1987  32.789
```

can you please help how could i do this for a huge number of records?

Answer (score 4):

use `REPLACE` on this,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET cost = REPLACE(REPLACE(cost, '$', ''), ',',''),
    distance = REPLACE(distance, 'miles', '')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8828/1)

Comment: MySQL docs say self-referencing the column is not possible (for DML `REPLACE`). *"You cannot refer to values from the current row and use them in the new row."*

Comment: Won't this leave the values in text fields? Wouldn't it be better to convert to numeric types so these values can be used effectively in calculations?

Comment: @sixeightzero I was reading the DML `REPLACE`, not the string function.

Comment: @njk weird, it's working on sqlfiddle. :D can i have that link?

Comment: @JohnWoo [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is the doc for the DML `REPLACE`.

Comment: @njr101 converting the column into numeric type will be the second step after it has been replaced. you can't alter it when some values are not compatible with the type.

Comment: i think it's better to add a space before ' miles', otherwise that space is left in the field

Comment: @john ok i'll delete my answer since it's identical to yours..... you are too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
       replace(substring(price, 2, length(price)), '.', ''),  
       replace(distance, 'miles', '')
from *tablename*
```